# how to parse using xml parser in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser

Am able to parse 
***< name>Walmart< /name>***
using xml parser

but how to parse
***< s:image link="http://i.walmartimages.com/i/p/00/02/72/42/77/0002724277837_500X500.jpg"/>***
using xml parse in iphone.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of doing this. My personal favorite is using Xpath via [TFHpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple). Xpath is clearly documented and easy to understand at W3schools. Sorry, I can't link to it. Spam filter prevents it.

I've used this approach for all sorts of things, and it is also great to note that you can use this library with HTML data as well.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution......

No need to go to parser libraries...
We can parse such tags using **NSXMLParser** with the help of **attribute** concepts....

thanks for you all for helping me....

cheers